# Calendar Control - Display Quarters

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I'm trying to put together a calendar control(WPF) which will only show dates from a collection of dates which are quarterly in nature.

For example my collection(a list of Datetime objects) of dates will be as follows

```
31/Mar/2012

31/Dec/2012

30/Sep/2012

30/Jun/2012

30/Mar/2012
```

Now I can use the calendar control and set it's display mode to Year just to show the year-month view, but how can I set the control to blackout the months which are not available in the above collection and only show the months available in the collection?

Please note that the question has 2 parts:

1. how do I blackout a month while display mode of the calendar is set to year?
2. how do i blackout the months which are not part of the collection?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply find the minimum and maximum dates and then do this:

```
calendarControl.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(minDate, maxDate));
```

further you can do ranges, so let's say it's not that straight forward and you need multiple ranges (though it doesn't look like it from your question) then you could do this:

```
calendarControl.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd));
```

further you can even black out a specific date like this:

```
calendarControl.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(blackoutDate));
```

so in your case it might be easiest to just black out certain dates. Just loop through the list and leverage the last code example I gave you.

Comment: This does not blackout the month when the displaymode is set to year.

Comment: @Mike, are you expecting the month to literally not even be visible? Because the dates aren't selectable right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public void BlackOutDates(startDate, endDate, periodInDays)
{
    while(startDate < endDate)
    {
        calender.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(startDate, startDate.AddDays(periodInDays));
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(periodInDays+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not blackout the month when the displaymode is set to year.